# How to map an array with getServerSideProps in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to use the data retrieved from the Twitch API to create a list of streamers. But when I try to map the props from `getServerSideProps` I get a blank page. If I `console.log`, I get all the data, but on mapping, I get nothing.

I am using the following code:

```
export default function Home( { users } ) {

  console.log(users);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Twitch</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

     
      <div className=''>
       {users.map((user) => (
         <div key={user.id}>
            <h1>{user.display_name}</h1>
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

            
            
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
  const data = await res.json()
  const [users] = await Promise.all([data])
  return {
      props: {
          users
      }
  }
}
```

The `console.log` returns:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {data: Array(1)}
1: {data: Array(1)}
2: {data: Array(1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should check back to what the data looks like in your console log.

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {data: Array(1)}
1: {data: Array(1)}
2: {data: Array(1)}
```

See anything against your template that might not be returning what you think it is?

I see a list of objects with a data array, so potentially your template code may look more like:

```
{users.map((user) => (
  <div key={user.data[0].id}>
    <h1>{user.data[0].display_name}</h1>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Well yes, that worked! Thank you. I'm just trying to figure out why it worked. I'm now learning JS, so some things still confuse me.

Comment: Take a look at how getServerSideProps() creates the users array. Add a log/debugger to every line if it helps, but you should be able to see how the data is being formatted there.